# Conditional PDF of $X_1$ conditionally on $X_1 + X_2 > a$ if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. exponential

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Thank you all in advance. I'm trying to calculate:

pdf of $(X_1 | X_1 + X_2 > a)$ ($X_1$,$X_2$ ~ exp($\lambda$))
rewriting $$ X_3 = X_1 + X_2$$
then we need to find
$$P(X_1 | X_3 > a)$$

I know that the pdf of the sum is gamma.  I also tried to apply the memoryless property, but didn't find it applicable/useful.

Then 
$$p_{X_1 | X_3 > a}=\frac{p_{X_1, X_3 > a}(x_1, x_3)}{p_{X_3 > a}( x_3)}$$

The denominator is 
$$1 - P(X_3<a) = 1 - ???$$

The numerator:

$$p_{X_1, X_3 > a}(x_1, x_3)=P(X_1=x, X_3 > a)= P(X_1=x_1, X_3 > a)=P(X_1=x_1)P(X_2>X_3-X_1)$$

Then I don't know what do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}
X_1\sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda) & \implies \mathsf f_{_{X_1}}(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[0,\infty)}}\!(x) 
\\[1ex]
X_2\sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda) & \implies \mathsf f_{_{X_2}}(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[0,\infty)}}\!(y)
\\ & \implies \mathsf f_{_{X_2}}\!(y-z) = \lambda e^{-\lambda (y-z)}\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[z,\infty)}}\!(y)
\\[3ex]
\mathsf f_{_{X_1,X_1+X_2}}\!(x, y) & = \mathsf f_{_{X_1}}\!(x)\;\mathsf f_{_{X_2}}\!(y-x)
\\ & = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[0,\infty)}}(x)\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[x,\infty)}}(y)
\\[3ex]
\mathsf f_{_{X_1+X_2}}\!(y) & = \int_0^\infty \mathsf f_{_{X_1}}\!(z)\mathsf f_{_{X_2}}\!(y-z)\operatorname{d}z
\\ & = \lambda^2 \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda y} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[z,\infty)}}(y)\operatorname{d}z
\\[4ex]
\mathsf f(X_1=x\mid X_1+X_2>a) & =\frac{
\displaystyle \int_a^\infty \mathsf f_{_{X_1,X_1+X_2}}\!(x,y)\operatorname{d}y 
}{
\displaystyle  \int_a^\infty \mathsf f_{_{X_1+X_2}}\!(y)\operatorname{d}y
}
\\[2ex] & =\frac{\displaystyle 
\int_{a}^\infty\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[0,\infty)}}(x)\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[x,\infty)}}(y)\operatorname{d}y
}{\displaystyle 
\lambda^2 \int_0^\infty \int_a^\infty e^{-\lambda y} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[z,\infty)}}(y) \operatorname{d} y \operatorname{d}z 
}
\\[2ex]
 & =\frac{\displaystyle 
\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[0,a)}}(x) \int_{a}^\infty\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y} \operatorname{d}y
+ \operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[a,\infty)}}(x) \int_{x}^\infty\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y} \operatorname{d}y
}{\displaystyle 
\lambda^2 \int_0^a \int_a^\infty e^{-\lambda y} \operatorname{d} y \operatorname{d}z 
+
\lambda^2 \int_a^\infty \int_z^\infty e^{-\lambda y} \operatorname{d} y \operatorname{d}z 
}
\\[2ex]
 & =\frac{\displaystyle 
\lambda e^{-\lambda a} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[0,a)}}(x) 
+ \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[a,\infty)}}(x)
}{\displaystyle 
\lambda \int_0^a e^{-\lambda a} \operatorname{d}z 
+
\lambda \int_a^\infty e^{-\lambda z} \operatorname{d}z 
}
\\[2ex]
 & =\frac{\displaystyle 
\lambda e^{-\lambda a} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[0,a)}}(x) 
+ \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[a,\infty)}}(x)
}{\displaystyle  \lambda a e^{-\lambda a} + e^{-\lambda a} }
\\[2ex]
 & =\dfrac{\lambda }{\lambda a + 1 } \left(
\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[0,a)}}(x) 
+ e^{\lambda (a-x)}\operatorname{\bf 1}_{_{[a,\infty)}}(x)
\right)
\\[4ex]
\mathsf f(X_1=x\mid X_1+X_2>a) & = \dfrac{\lambda }{\lambda a + 1 } \begin{cases} 1 & : 0\le x\lt a 
\\ e^{ \lambda (a-x)} & : a\le x
\end{cases}
\end{align}$

Comment: thank you very much. I have seen many examples of such calculations, but the conditional part is always given as an equality. I'm trying to understand why you used integrals in the last equation. The formula I have is $\frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$ I see that you left the f(x,y) in the integral form from the above and just changed the lower limit of integration from 0 to a. Why can we change the limit? If you know of any examples where such situation is described or how to look for it, please let me know.

Comment: @user174636 It's because the conditional in this case is a mass ($Y>a$) rather than a density ($Y=a$). So we're integrating over the domain $y \in (a,\infty)$.